# Python - Count of pairwise nonzeros in rows with Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, linear-algebra

I am trying to calculate the number of common nonzero numbers between rows. This is to calculate Discounted Similarity between users by their in common reviews.  I am using a Pandas DataFrame.

```
#creating a dataframe
test_movie_list = [[7,6,7,4,5,4],[6,7,0,4,3,4],[0,3,3,1,1,0],[1,2,2,3,3,4],[1,0,1,2,3,3]]
df_test = pd.DataFrame(test_movie_list)
df_test = df_test.replace(0, np.NaN)
# Array of common nonzeros between row 1 and all others would be [5, 5, 3, 5, 4]
    0       1       2       3   4   5
0   7.0     6.0     7.0     4   5   4.0
1   6.0     7.0     NaN     4   3   4.0
2   NaN     3.0     3.0     1   1   NaN
3   1.0     2.0     2.0     3   3   4.0
4   1.0     NaN     1.0     2   3   3.0
```

I can do it by converting to a boolean array and doing a sum product or dot product between every row but it seems like there has to be a more efficient way.

```
nulls = df_test.notnull()
common_element_list = np.zeros([len(nulls),len(nulls)])
for i in range(len(nulls)):
    for j in range(len(nulls)):
        common_element_list[i,j] = sum(nulls.loc[i] & nulls.loc[j]) # sum number of pairwise Trues
print(common_element_list) # Matrix of common nonNaN elements
[[ 6.  5.  4.  6.  5.]
 [ 5.  5.  3.  5.  4.]
 [ 4.  3.  4.  4.  3.]
 [ 6.  5.  4.  6.  5.]
 [ 5.  4.  3.  5.  5.]]
```